# jquery ajax call not giving response in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying jquery ajax in codeigniter for first time. I am not getting any response from ajax call. when I click button, I can verify data using alerts before j.ajax but no response to actual ajax call. Please help to find problem.

My view is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var j=jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(){
    j("#b").click(function(){
        var scode=j("#a").val();
        var baseurl="<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
        $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: baseurl + 'ajax/aj', 
         data: {txt:scode},
        success:function(response){
           j("#c").val(response);
         }
     });
    });
});
</script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="a"></label>
  <input type="text" name="a" id="a" />
  <input name="b" type="button" value="click" id="b" />
  <input type="text" name="c" id="c" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my controller is:

```
<?php
class ajax Extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();  
    $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('ajax_trial');
    }
    public function aj(){
        $x=$this->input->get('txt');
        echo $x;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any value in controller for `$x`?

Comment: I am not using model

Comment: try debugging in console.

Comment: in controller i mean..

Comment: you can check ajax call in browser console please check that what happen there

Comment: this should be `post`, not `get` $x=$this->input->get('txt');

Comment: I get this error in browser console

Comment: Try $x = $_REQUEST['txt'].

Comment: @Amit which error?

Comment: I get this error in browser consoleUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (ajax:16)
    at HTMLInputElement.handle (http://[::1]/ebizport/js/jquery-latest.js:3001)
    at HTMLInputElement.eventHandle (http://[::1]/ebizport/js/jquery-latest.js:2635)

Comment: I tried by changing j by $ but console gives this error<br>XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[::1]/ebizport/ajax/aj?txt=aa. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost'; is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I just included 'header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');' in controller and problem is solved. thank you all again.

Answer (score 2):

Dear friend You send data using post method and you print data using get method you must be use POST method....

```
<?php
class ajax Extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();  
    $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('ajax_trial');
    }
    public function aj(){
        $x=$this->input->post('txt');
        echo $x;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the POST in ajax call to GET as u are using get method to receive the variable .I tried your code if your click function is working then by doing this small change it will work:-

```
jQuery("#b").click(function(){
            var scode=jQuery("#a").val();
            var baseurl="<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: baseurl + 'test/aj',
                data: {txt:scode},
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    jQuery("#c").val(response);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed that you are using j for jquery but using $.ajax for ajax call?

Comment: I tried by changing j by $ butconsole gives this error<br>XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[::1]/ebizport/ajax/aj?txt=aa. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

please use this in controller

error_reporting(0);

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");